# Setting Oracle AQ of type SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE from OCCI / C++

Tags: c++, oracle, jms, oracle-aq, advanced-queuing

I have an application written in C++ that needs to populate a queue of type SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE.

I am using OCCI, a C++ API to manipulate Oracle database and I have successfully populated queues of other types.

Is it possible to populate a queue of type SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE using OCCI?

Comment: I'm not sure. at least you can call an anonymous PL/SQL block, which will do it. AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE is a Oracle datatype, which has constructor implemented as Java stored procedure. So at least you can call PL/SQL block and construct this object on database side.

But maybe there are other ways too.

Comment: Brilliant idea. I will try this one if no other solution is available. Thanks